# What are "Taglist" and "Tag Treelist" field types in Sitecore 9?

Tags: sxa, fieldtype

I found "Taglist" and "Tag Treelist" in the list of available field types in my current instance of Sitecore 9:

[image]

but i can't find any sort of documentation on them on the official Sitecore website, nor anywhere actually.

Can anyone tell me what are they used for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both field types are coming from Sitecore Experience Accelerator (SXA). You can find their implementation in Sitecore.XA.Feature.Taxonomy.dll precisely in Sitecore.XA.Feature.Taxonomy.FieldTypes namespace.

**TagTreeList** is used by "Tag Cloud" rendering.

This rendering looks like this (right column below Archive):

[image]

**TagList** is used by "Tag List" Rendering.

Renderings can be found in Sitecore under /sitecore/layout/Renderings/Feature/Experience Accelerator/Taxonomy in "master" database.

They are defined in Sitecore.XA.Feature.Taxonomy.config

by this config patch

```
<controlSources>
  <source patch:before="*[@namespace='Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor']" mode="on" namespace="Sitecore.XA.Feature.Taxonomy.FieldTypes" assembly="Sitecore.XA.Feature.Taxonomy" prefix="content"/>
</controlSources>
```

and also in "core" database in /sitecore/system/Field types/List Types/Taglist and /sitecore/system/Field types/List Types/Tag Treelist items.

Small details can be found here about renderings - https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/building_the_layout/renderings/the_sxa_renderings_and_rendering_variants#_Engagement

Both fields usage can be seen in really cool Alan Plocieniak's blog post -> https://alan-null.github.io/2017/12/sxa-blog#search-results-page.

Comment: thank you for that, i didn't know it was an SXA feature rather than plain sitecore. I have a question though : to use taglist, do i need to, in some way, add 'tags' to my pages in SXA?

Comment: @mie No problem. Just follow Alan's blog post and you will find out how to use these renderings / fields